# is there a personalization string to pull Landing Page name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to pull the name of a landing page and post it to a DataExtension via the WebCollect form.

Is there some personalization string or AMPScript variable that I can reference on my landing page to obtain its name.

It would be great if i could do soemthing similar to the following:

```
%%[
VAR @LPname
SET @LPname= [Landing Page Name]

IF not empty(@LPname) THEN]%% 
My landing page name is %%=v(@LPname)=%%. 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the built-in personalization strings are listed on [**Personalization String wiki page**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/).  There aren't any for Landing Page names.

There's nothing stopping you from creating a variable for it -- like in your example.  It'd be a static value, obviously.

Not sure why you'd conditionally hide/show content based on the name of the page.  Perhaps you can update your question with some additional details about your use-case.

Comment: I just need to pass the landing page name to a form variable so that it can be captured alongside the other form elements to a data extension using the DEManager.

Answer (score -1):

In classic content microsites, %%emailname_%% will return the "name" property of the current page.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, I have a page named "SSJS Test," and on that page, %%emailname_%% was replaced with "SSJS Test." I tested it before posting.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs did you ever test this yourself?

Comment: Did you arrive at your test page by clicking a link in your email or did you go to the page directly?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs We generally link to landing pages by URL like `https://hostname/lp-name/%%_subscriberkey%%` so we can use query string parameters client-side without fuss, and the behavior is as stated above; however, I'll concede that it's not a solution iff the link is constructed with the `%%=MicrositesURL()=%%` function.